# Editing Default Commands on Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, terminal, command-prompt

I am creating a Windows virtual machine and would like to edit the default commands for the command prompt like `tree` so that when that command is typed it will do what I want it to do. I found 'tree.com' in System32, but when I open it, it is gibberish. How might I be able to read and edit it?

Comment: what do you mean by `edit the default commands`? You can't edit the binaries (unless you want to reverse engineering). They are executable files, not scripts. And some commands don't even have a file for you to edit, because they're internal commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying basic Windows programs is not a good idea (in case you need them there not there anymore), but there's another approaches: `doskey`, based on UNIX `alias`es: this allows you to, when you enter `tree`, to start up another program instead. Help can be found under `doskey /?` and there are plenty of examples online.

Answer (score 0):

Files with extension .com are compiled executables. There is nothing to edit in there.